# How do I implement a Comparator using Generics?

Tags: java, generics

Just a minor problem with `Arraylist`. I want to sort a `ArrayList<Client>` by name.

```
Class Client{ String name; int phonenumber ..}
```

This code does the work, but i'm having a compiler warning: "uses unchecked or unsafe operations". Whats the problem?

```
 public void sortByName(){
    Collections.sort(ListofClients, new NameComparator());
 }
```

My comparator looks like this:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator{
  public int compare(Object client1, Object client) {
   String name1 = ((Client) client1).getName();
   String name2 = ((Client) client2).getName();

   return name1.toUpperCase()).compareTo(name2.toUpperCase(); 
  }
}
```

If i use "`implements Comparator<Client>` " i get a error: "NameComparator is not a abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Client, Client) in java.util.Comparator. Is my comparator wrong? sorry for this noob question, new to java

Comment: just return result straight away :)

Comment: @bruno Note that your Comparator does not handle null names.

Comment: Why should it if a valid Client object cannot have a null name.

Comment: Side Note: Use compareToIgnoreCase() instead of upper casing the values - it's much more efficient because it (a) enjoys the benefit of early termination, and (b) avoids having to create and collect two new Strings.

Comment: Also, there's no point in creating a new comparator each time; just create a static one and reuse it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you `implement Comparator<Client>` you need to change:

```
public int compare(Object client1, Object client) 
{
  ...
}
```

to this

```
public int compare(Client client1, Client client)
{
    // Now you don't have to cast your objects!
}
```

this is all because the definition of comparator

```
public interface Comparator<T>
{
    public compare(T o1, T o2);
}
```

Notice how the generic parameter T shows up in the method name.

An IDE like Eclipse / Netbeans / IntelliJ will help out in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I presume your list of clients is of the type

```
List<Client>
```

in which case your comparator should be of type `Comparator<Client>`, and perform the appropriate comparison (by name, in this case)