# How does Java's generics work?

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparable

Could anyone please help me understand how does Java's generics work? I understand the concept of it. But for this specific example of the code I don't clearly understand the compiler's error messages.

Example code:
Test class

```
// Test code 
public class A < ListType extends Comparable < ListType >> {
// To make the instance variable y
public int y;
// To make the instance variable s
public String s;

//Constructor Method
public A(int requiredY, String requiredS) {
y = requiredY;
s = requiredS;
}

more code here...
}
```

Then in a different class I wrote

```
List <A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
more code here...
Collections.sort(a)
```

The error message I am getting is

```
test.java:20: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<A>)
Collections.sort(a);
           ^
method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
  (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: A
    upper bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:

```
T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
```

I don't understand why is the compiler complaining about the type parameter. Shouldn't the collections work? Because the type parameters are both mutually comparable.

Comment: Note that this is not related to the Collections API, but with [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: In addition to the Java tutorial on generics (linked above) Chapter 5 of [Effective Java](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC) is basically required reading for using generics properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're writing your question wrong in order to hide the class names, or you're mistaken in representing the generics.

If what you're trying to do is making a class that could be sorted, you can implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in the class **A** as others have suggested.

```
public class A < ListType extends Comparable < ListType >> {
...
}
```

The above code would require the `class A` to accept a class that extends/implements `Comparable`, and use `ListType` as its type erasure.
Since you don't show how would you use the `ListType` to bound a type, I don't think this is what you want.

Usually generics are used to bound the type of parameter you can use in a class, in order to provide a type-safe operations in compile time.

```
import java.lang.Override;
public class A <ListType extends Comparable<ListType>>{
    ListType lt;
    A(ListType b){
        this.lt = b;
    }
    static class B implements Comparable<B>{
        B(){};
        @Override
        public int compareTo(B b){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    static class C implements Comparable<B>{
        C(){};
        @Override
        public int compareTo(B c){
            return 0;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        A<B> a = new A<B>(new B());   //OK
        A<C> _a = new A<C>(new C()); //ERROR: is not within bound
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Because `class C` is not implementing a `Comparable` class with itself, you cannot pass a `class C` variable to the `class A` constructor.
If you want to create a type that will accept any classes that extends `Comparable`, you could use a wildcard `?`.

```
public class A <ListType extends Comparable<?>>
```

or use a single capital letter as type for better code styling

```
public class A <T extends Comparable<?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `A` is not `Comparable`. Notice your type signature:

```
public class A<ListType extends Comparable<ListType>>
```

This says that `A` (which is a poor name for a concrete class, single-letter types are generally reserved for generic types) has a generic type `ListType`, and that `ListType` is `Comparable` with other `ListType` objects.

The signature of [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) expects to be passed a `List<T>` where `T` is a generic type that implements `Comparable`. Since `A` does not implement `Comparable` you cannot pass it to `Collections.sort()`.

You likely did not mean to define `A` the way you did. You probably intended to do something like this:

```
public class A<ListType> implements Comparable<A<ListType>>
```

This says both that `A` has a generic type called `ListType` and that `A` implements `Comparable` and therefore can be compared (and sorted) with other instances of `A`.

Since `A` now implements the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface you'll need to define a
`compareTo()` method on `A`.

Comment: That should be `implements Comparable<A<ListType>>`.

Comment: @dimo414 Thanks. But after trying to follow this approach, the compiler is giving me two warnings `javac test.java
Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` Could you tell me the reason for the warning?

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed if you follow the suggestion and run `javac` with the `-Xlint:unchecked` flag it will give you more information. There are also a number of [related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20unchecked%20cast) out there you can reference. Generally speaking this means you're making an unsafe cast (e.g. `List<String> ls = new ArrayList<Object>()`) but the only way to know for sure is to look at the code. If you can't figure it out consider posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how to use the [Comparator Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

To compare custom classes you need to implement your customized Comparator and then only you can use the Sorting method provided by the collections interface.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843391/1475228) for reference.